# How can I use the built-in flash with a legacy prime on a Nikon D3100?

Tags: nikon, flash, old-lenses, nikon-d3100, popup-flash

I purchased an older 50mm prime lens to use on my Nikon D3100. I know it will not meter or focus (and I can handle manual focus and exposure etc.) but I cannot get it to fire the on-camera flash. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know Nikons, so I'm posting as a comment, but is there a way to put the flash in a manual mode?  Without metering, TTL isn't going to work, so you'd have to manually set flash power too.

Answer (score 2):

I use a Nikon D3000 which should be similar.

In the camera menu (shooting menu, I think) you can control the power of the flash manually. Change the flash to manual rather than TTL, then set the power you would like (e.g. 1/2, 1/4, etc.).

It's slow, and I can't think of a quicker way for the on-camera flash, but it will at least allow you to use it.

Please let me know if that works. Good luck.